# Code works in Arduino Web editor but not in PlatformIO IDE or Arduino IDE with board Nicla Sense ME

Tags: arduino-ide, debugging, platformio

Here is the verbose for the Arduino IDE:

```
Flashing with command:/Users/hakan/.arduino-create/arduino/openocd/0.11.0-arduino2/bin/openocd -d2 -s /Users/hakan/.arduino-create/arduino/openocd/0.11.0-arduino2/share/openocd/scripts/ -f interface/cmsis-dap.cfg -c transport select swd; adapter speed 1000 -f target/nrf52.cfg -c telnet_port disabled; init; reset init; halt; adapter speed 10000; program {/var/folders/dy/qqk78q1956s1pb94hc4y_x5m0000gn/T/arduino-create-agent511362936/sketch_mar22a.elf}; reset run; shutdown

Open On-Chip Debugger 0.11.0+dev-gab95bac57-dirty (2021-05-11-10:57)

Licensed under GNU GPL v2

For bug reports, read

http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html

debug_level: 2

adapter speed: 1000 kHz

Info : CMSIS-DAP: SWD Supported

Info : CMSIS-DAP: FW Version = v1.0

Info : CMSIS-DAP: Serial# = AA7EAA93

Info : CMSIS-DAP: Interface Initialised (SWD)

Info : SWCLK/TCK = 1 SWDIO/TMS = 1 TDI = 0 TDO = 0 nTRST = 0 nRESET = 1

Info : CMSIS-DAP: Interface ready

Info : clock speed 1000 kHz

Info : SWD DPIDR 0x2ba01477

Info : nrf52.cpu: hardware has 6 breakpoints, 4 watchpoints

Info : starting gdb server for nrf52.cpu on 3333

Info : Listening on port 3333 for gdb connections

target halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread

xPSR: 0x01000000 pc: 0x00006dc4 msp: 0x20010000

target halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread

xPSR: 0x01000000 pc: 0x00006dc4 msp: 0x20010000

** Programming Started **

Info : nRF52832-CIAA(build code: E0) 512kB Flash, 64kB RAM

Warn : Adding extra erase range, 0x0001d8f8 .. 0x0001dfff

** Programming Finished **

shutdown command invoked
```

Here is the one for PlatformIO:

```
AVAILABLE: blackmagic, cmsis-dap, jlink, nrfjprog, nrfutil, sam-ba
CURRENT: upload_protocol = cmsis-dap
openocd -d2 -s /Users/hakan/.platformio/packages/tool-openocd/scripts -f interface/cmsis-dap.cfg -f target/nrf52.cfg -c "transport select swd;" -c "adapter speed 1000" -c "program {.pio/build/nicla_sense_me/firmware.hex}  verify reset; shutdown;"
xPack OpenOCD x86_64 Open On-Chip Debugger 0.11.0+dev (2021-10-17-00:18)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
        http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
debug_level: 2

Info : auto-selecting first available session transport "swd". To override use 'transport select <transport>'.
Warn : Transport "swd" was already selected
swd
adapter speed: 1000 kHz

Info : CMSIS-DAP: SWD  supported
Info : CMSIS-DAP: FW Version = v1.0
Info : CMSIS-DAP: Serial# = AA7EAA93
Info : CMSIS-DAP: Interface Initialised (SWD)
Info : SWCLK/TCK = 1 SWDIO/TMS = 1 TDI = 0 TDO = 0 nTRST = 0 nRESET = 1
Info : CMSIS-DAP: Interface ready
Info : clock speed 1000 kHz
Info : SWD DPIDR 0x2ba01477
Info : nrf52.cpu: Cortex-M4 r0p1 processor detected
Info : nrf52.cpu: target has 6 breakpoints, 4 watchpoints
Info : starting gdb server for nrf52.cpu on 3333
Info : Listening on port 3333 for gdb connections
target halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread 
xPSR: 0x01000000 pc: 0x000008e4 msp: 0x20000400
** Programming Started **
Info : nRF52832-CIAA(build code: E0) 512kB Flash, 64kB RAM
Warn : Adding extra erase range, 0x00052738 .. 0x00052fff
** Programming Finished **
** Verify Started **
** Verified OK **
** Resetting Target **
shutdown command invoked
```

`Platform.ini` content:

```
[env:nicla_sense_me]
platform = nordicnrf52
board = nicla_sense_me
framework = arduino
monitor_speed = 115200
debug_speed = 1000
upload_protocol = cmsis-dap

lib_deps = 
    Wire
    /Users/marcopolo/Documents/PlatformIO/Projects/C1/include/Arduino_BHY2
    /Users/marcopolo/Documents/PlatformIO/Projects/C1/include/ArduinoBLE-master
```

The code is a very basic `blink` example.

Edit: Here is the error:

```
++ MbedOS Fault Handler ++

FaultType: HardFault

Context:
R   0: 20010000
R   1: 0001BB1C
R   2: 00000005
R   3: 00000000
R   4: 20010000
R   5: 20010000
R   6: 0001BB1C
R   7: 00000000
R   8: 00000000
R   9: 00000000
R  10: 00000000
R  11: 00000000
R  12: FFFFFFFF
SP   : 20002CA0
LR   : 00010CB7
PC   : 00013B3E
xPSR : A1070000
PSP  : 20002C80
MSP  : 2000FFC0
CPUID: 410FC241
HFSR : 40000000
MMFSR: 00000000
BFSR : 00000082
UFSR : 00000000
DFSR : 00000000
AFSR : 00000000
BFAR : 20010000
Mode : Thread
Priv : Privileged
Stack: PSP

-- MbedOS Fault Handler --



++ MbedOS Error Info ++
Error Status: 0x80FF013D Code: 317 Module: 255
Error Message: Fault exception
Location: 0x13B3E
Error Value: 0x2000303C
Current Thread: main Id: 0x20001A78 Entry: 0x13057 StackSize: 0xC00 StackMem: 0x200020D0 SP: 0x20002CA0 
For more info, visit: https://mbed.com/s/error?error=0x80FF013D&tgt=NICLA
-- MbedOS Error Info --
```

Edit: Same board works pretty fine in **Windows OS.**

Comment: Verbose compilation and compare parameters. For example micro:bit had issue with -DNRF52 (second port wasn't available - but for 52832 it's valid define) and -DUSE_LFXO used external 32k crystal configuration for millis(), but there is none on the board and so on...

Comment: I appreciate if you can elaborate.

Comment: I'm reading about that board and you might be able to run it in debugger - you can just step through the program and what is causing that hard fault. (micro:bit has 1-click debug too same this board)

Comment: @KIIV, I have just found out that the board works fine in Windows. Regarding the cause, the program is a very simple blink.